# Simple ngFor errors in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to loop through every object in an array in angular 2.

here my main component:

```
  selector: 'exploreGuide',
  templateUrl: 'exploreGuide.template.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./exploreGuide.style.scss']
})
export class exploreGuide {
  config: any;
  newAnnouncement: Announcement;
  deals: Deal[];
  events: venEvent[];
  announcements: Announcement[];


  constructor(config: AppConfig) {
    this.config = config.getConfig();

  }
  addAnnouncement(event: Event, announcement: Announcement) {
    event.preventDefault();
  this.announcements.push(announcement);
  }
}
```

Here my object defined:

```
export class Announcement{
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

and here's the actual template file:

```
<section class = 'widget'>
  <h1 class="page-title" style="align-self: center;"> Announcements</h1>
  <div class="widget-controls">
    <a data-widgster="expand" title="Expand" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
    <a data-widgster="collapse" title="Collapse" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <a href="#" data-widgster="close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class = 'widget-body'>

          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newAnnouncement.title" name="title"  placeholder="Add Title...">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newAnnouncement.description" name="Description"  placeholder="Add Description...">
    <input type="button" (click)="addAnnouncement(newAnnouncement)">


    </div>
</section>
<br>
<ul>
  <li ngFor="let Announcement of announcements">
    {{Announcement.title}}
    {{Announcement.description}}

  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm new to angular and mostly come from a java background, i'm confused as to how I actually have it list out every object in the array.

Comment: What does “errors” mean? Please make sure to include error messages in your question. Anyway, try `*ngFor="…"`.

Comment: you just need to change  `announcements: Announcement[];` to   `announcements: Announcement[] = [];`. And yes, @Ryan is right, you need `*ngFor="..."`

Comment: sorry, by errors I mean when I inspect in chrome it tells me "cannot read property "title" as undefined".

Comment: @Ryan and @Aluan Haddad are correct, make sure the array object is initialized and consider using `*ngIf="announcements"` before rendering data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your properties like so

```
announcements: Announcement[] = [];
newAnnouncement: Announcement = {};
```

Furthermore, as noted by @Ryan in their  comment on your question, your `ngFor` syntax is invalid. It needs to begin with an asterisk (*) like so

```
<li *ngFor="let announcement of announcements">
</li>
```

Note that I'm using lower camel case for the variable name by convention, so make sure all of the casing matches one way or another.

Comment: This answer looks good for the most part, but the announcements assignment is wrong. You're assigning an object to an array field. Pls fix it to `announcements: Announcement[] = [];`, then I can upvote this

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there are two possible answer for the same to prevent from error messages.

1. Use `*ngIf` as the parent of *ngFor to check whether the obeject/array has properties on which you are going to iterate or not, and by using *ngIf angular will not allow to pass control to *ngFor untill array is not empty. as @yoav used in recent answer so you can use this as.

   ```
   <ul *ngIf="announcements !== null">
   // or can use like this
   //<ul *ngIf="announcements.length > 0">
       <li *ngFor="let Announcement of announcements">
   .....
   </li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Instead of using *ngIf better to use `Elevis Operator(?.)` in the `*ngFor` itself, this will not allow to throw error if property are not there on array/object iteration, use it like this

   ```
   <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let Announcement of announcements">
     {{Announcement?.title}}
     {{Announcement?.description}}
    </li>
   </ul>
   ```

PS: Make sure your syntax is right for *ngFor. like i provided in my answer.

Comment: From the OP, we can infer that he wants to be able to build up the list if it is empty. You don't provide the solution for that, just a guard that will prevent the component from ever doing anything at all. The initialization which would solve the problem is frankly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can initiate the variables inside the constructor which is a best practice and advisable one as below

```
constructor(config: AppConfig) {
     this.announcements = [];
     this.newAnnouncement = {};
     this.config = config.getConfig();
 }
```

In addition to the ***ngFor** in which you missed *. 
It is mandated in angular2 that **all the structural directives** are prefixed with `*` to differentiate from custom directives.

Comment: This is the same answer as mine except you are using in constructor initialization. How is that a better practice than initializing them inline?

Comment: Also, `this.newAnnouncement: Announcement = {};` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `It is mandated in angular2 that all the structural directives are prefixed with * to differentiate from custom directives.` but you can write custom structural directives....